# Object to primitive conversion in Javascript: Please why isn't the valueOf() method called since there is not toString() method

Tags: javascript, object, tostring, primitive, value-of

```js
let obj = {
  valueOf() {
    return "2";
  }
};

alert(obj);
```

I thought in the absence of **toString()** the **valueOf()** will be called when a string is expected.

Comment: Why did you think alert would require a primitive? `+obj` gives `2`, as expected

Comment: doesn't alert() always convert it's argument to a string?

Comment: Yes, but that's different than a primitive value - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: @jonrsharpe well actually i do see it does call valueOf if it doesn't find toString method, look at my answer. since here we are not creating a pure object so it find toString on prototype and won't call valueOf.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read in it that when a string value is required, toString() will be called which is the case with alert(). But since there is no toString() shouldn't it fall back on valueOf()?

Comment: Their point is that there *is* a toString, the one returning `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: So my error was I thought toString() was absent but isn't. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not call because this find `toString` in prototype chain, if we create a object without any prototype it will call

```js
let obj = Object.create(null)

obj.valueOf =
  function() {
    return "2";
  }

alert(obj);
```

Comment: Okay I know that every object has toString() as [object Object] even if I didn't add it as a property in the object. So what you're saying is if I call Object.create(null) it removes the toString() prototype?

Comment: @Israel yes this is used to setup prototype to null, or in normally it is called a pure object

Comment: If that is the case then why does toString() get called if I replace the valueOf() in my question with toString() and I change the alert() to statement that requires a number not a string

Comment: @Israel it searches in prototype chain for toString so if you object has toString it just calls that function, if not then it searches down the prototype if found call that function if not then it calls valueOf

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you

Comment: Then what about this

Comment: If I replace the valueOf() in the code with toString(). And I replace the alert() with a statement that requires a number. Why does the toString() still get called if there is a prototype already for valueOf() that returns the object itself

Comment: @Israel can you post example of statement you're talking about, the best is you can use `[Symbol.toPrimitive]` on object to see in what hint the object is getting converted.

Comment: Okay. I've posted a new question on that. I am aware of the [Symbol.toPrimitive]. I just want to understand prototypes better. Thanks for your help